# Google app script : New variable keeps reference of source variable

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, reference, google-sheets

We have variable "a" and we want to create variable "b" as a mirror of "a" variable and then change one of its elements.

**Code**

```
function h(){
var a=[[1,2,3]]
var b=a;
b[0][0]="test"
Logger.log(b)
Logger.log(a)
}
```

**Output**

```
[[test,2,3]]
[[test,2,3]]
```

Why is this happening? Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This referes to another question:

[Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

You may test some suggested solutions. I've tested this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23245968/5372400

The code:

```
function h(){
  var a=[[1,2,3]];
  var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
  b[0][0]="test";
  Logger.log(b);
  Logger.log(a);
}
```

result is

```
[[test, 2, 3]]
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

---

Looks like, `javascript` like `c` does not do array assignments.

Comment: I made a function using you suggestion and worked fluently everywhere in my project. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deep copy value in array b for this you can use slice method :

arr2 = arr1.slice();

Below is your code with some modifications:

```
function h(){
var a=[1,2,3];
var b= a.slice();
b[0]="test";
console.log(b);
console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but as I was using arrays and objects Max's solution worked better.